# TextInput full view in row direction

Tags: react-native, view

I ma new to React native development. In my application I have login screen. In laogin screen I have two text inputs along with images. I have taken image and Text input in one view and given flex direction as row. And I have given text input as alignSelf stretch. So here my issue is I need full length of text input along with image. But if I removed flex direction then will get full length of the screen. The following is the code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,TouchableOpacity,StatusBar,Image} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Welcome",
    header: null,
  }
  render() {
    // const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
           barStyle="light-content"
           backgroundColor="#2f5597"
        />
        <Image source={require('../../app/images/ic_accountlist.png')} style={styles.logo}/>

        <View style={styles.loginView}>
          <View >
             <Image source={require('../../app/images/ic_userid.png')}  />
             <TextInput placeholder="Acct No/User Id" style={styles.textInput} underlineColorAndroid={'rgb(0,0,0)'}></TextInput>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.user}>
            <Image source={require('../../app/images/ic_password.png')}  />
            <TextInput placeholder="Password" style={styles.textInput} underlineColorAndroid={'rgb(0,0,0)'}></TextInput>
          </View>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin} onPress={this.login}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Log In</Text></TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }

  login=()=>{
    // alert("testing......");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCF0',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color:'#FF0000',
  },
  textInput: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    padding: 10,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight:0,
  },
  btnLogin:{
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#2f5597',
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    paddingLeft: 50,
    paddingRight: 50,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  user:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  logo :{
    marginTop: 100,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  loginView:{
    marginTop: 60,
  }
});
```

And the following is the output I am getting

[image]

And here I need the text input full along with image. Like the below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use the `alignSelf` property. Instead, you have to use `flex: 1`:

```
textInput: {
  flex: 1,
  padding: 10,
  marginLeft: 5,
  marginRight: 0,   
},
```

`flex: 1` is a shorthand notation, so you could also use explicitly `flexGrow: 1` to achieve the same effect:

```
textInput: {
  flexGrow: 1,
  padding: 10,
  marginLeft: 5,
  marginRight: 0,   
},
```

You can read more about `flex` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Result (ignore the different icon):

[image: Screenshot from SM-G960F]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `flex: 1` to textInput style

```
textInput: {
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  padding: 10,
  marginLeft: 5,
  marginRight:0,
  flex: 1
}
```